# Google Chrome not selected when ran using RF and Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, robotframework

Im running my tests using Robot Framework 2.7 and Selenium 2.18. I need to run the scripts that I have in 3 different browsers (FF9,IE8, Google Chrome). I noticed that when running my scripts in Google Chrome, upon execution the main window is not selected and causing my 
tests to fail. I've tried using Select Window and Execute Javascript window.focus() keywords but it seems not to select the google chrome browser. 
Any suggestions?

Note:For FF9 and IE8, upon running the main window is always selected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this should be a problem , make sure you don't have any Google chrome windows open while running the tests, other than this there shouldn't be anything wrong ... I am running robot tests, the tests for FF are almost always compatible with tests on chrome

Comment: I tried running my test scripts with no other google chrome windows open and when the scripts are running the window is still not selected.

Answer (score 0):

If the window you are trying to select is the last opened window then try

**Select Window   new**

When we give argument as new it selects the latest opened browser window.

Make sure you are using robot to launch the browser as selenium will attach to a browser not opened by it.